# What did the Pharros's Lockstone do in No-man's Wharf?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I just bought a Pharros locks tone to use for the one in no mans wharf, but I'm not sure if it was a waste using it there, all I saw was a big light (and it's still here) go up then one of those crazy monsters look like when "Ahhhh! The sun it BURNS!!!!!!!"
Anyways, I just want to know what happened.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the weird creatures huh? But I would also like to know what that creature is, it's the black thing with weird arms and its spine sticking out, along with no face beside a big freakin' mouth that only looks like it was meant for breathing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function of the Lockstone contraption is to light the lantern that's hanging high up in the air. This will light up much of the area, making it less necessary to use your own torch.

Bloatheads (the spider-looking enemies) are also scared of light, which you may have noticed if you approached one with your torch out. When the lantern is lit via the Lockstone contraption, they will generally confine themselves to building interiors and other dimly-lit areas, which may make your travels through the area a little bit easier.

Comment: At first I didn't do the torch thing, I usually never use the thing (causes it to pile up, the goo thing is I have up to an hour of torch time) and after a while I figured out by myself, all I wanted to know was if it did anything else.